# Flat roof with deep Skylights that create heat

Tags: ceiling

The roof has 40x41" skylights which in the desert creates a lot of heat. Will there be a problem later if the opening at the ceiling is drywalled and sealed?

Comment: Have you considered some type of UV/heat blocking coating rather than boarding them up?  They will still heat the sheetrock "plug" that you put over them.

Comment: So far the test indicates that the heat is not transferring to the inside ceiling. But I am concerned with the heat in the space getting no venting.

Comment: The outside of the skylight was coated with a white exterior coat. However, the heat still came through and the esthetics of the paint is not nice.

Comment: Why can't you shade them on the exterior from direct sun?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's likely that any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion, and so off-topic here. But, let's see if you get any good answers.